# Insert mean and standard deviation in graph made in R

Tags: r

How do I insert two dashed horizontal lines on my chart, one indicating the mean and the other the mean + standard deviation with de condition below?

The average will be calculated based on the day of the week chosen. In this case my database has the day 01/08 and 08/08, which refer to a Sunday, so the mean will be according to the sum of the values of D1 for that particular day, which are for 01/08 = 0 + 1 + 0 + 0 + 5 = 6 and for 08/08 = 0 + 1 + 0 + 0 + 9 + 4 = 14, then the mean will be = (6 + 14) / 2 = 10, the standard deviation in this case is 5.65.

Executable code below:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)

df <- structure(
  list(date = c("2021-08-01","2021-08-01","2021-08-01","2021-08-01","2021-08-01",
                "2021-08-08","2021-08-08","2021-08-08","2021-08-08","2021-08-08","2021-08-08",
                "2021-08-13","2021-08-13","2021-08-13","2021-08-13","2021-08-13"),
       Week= c("Sunday","Sunday","Sunday","Sunday","Sunday","Sunday","Sunday","Sunday",
               "Sunday","Sunday","Sunday","Friday","Friday","Friday","Friday","Friday"),
       D1 = c(0,1,0,0,5,0,1,0,0,9,4,3,4,5,6,7), DR01 = c(2,1,0,0,3,0,1,0,1,7,2,3,4,6,7,8), 
       DR02 = c(2,0,0,0,4,2,1,0,1,4,2,3,4,5,6,7),  DR03 = c(2,0,0,2,6,2,0,0,1,5,2,2,4,5,7,5),
       DR04 = c(2,0,0,5,6,2,0,0,3,7,2,3,4,5,6,4),  DR05 = c(2,0,0,5,6,2,0,0,7,7,2,3,4,5,6,7), 
       DR06 = c(2,0,0,5,7,2,0,0,7,7,1,3,5,6,7,8),  DR07 = c(2,0,0,6,9,2,0,0,7,8,1,3,5,6,4,3)), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))


scatter_date <- function(dt, dta = df) {
  dta %>%
    mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>%
    filter(date == ymd(dt)) %>%
    summarize(across(starts_with("DR"), sum)) %>%
    pivot_longer(everything(), names_pattern = "DR(.+)", values_to = "val") %>%
    mutate(name = as.numeric(name)) %>%
    plot(xlab = "Days", ylab = "Types", xlim = c(0, 7))
  
  
}
scatter_date("2021-08-01")
```

[image]

**Excel:**

[image]

Comment: If you are using the base `plot()` function to make your plot, you can add lines on top using `abline()` after you've called `plot`. For example `abline(h=12)` would draw a horizontal line at Types=12. You can make it dashed by also passing in the `lty=` parameter (lty = line type). 1 is solid but you can try different values like 2, 3, 4, etc for different types of dashed lines.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But do you know how I can make this line of the mean according to the consideration I enter for calculating the mean?

Comment: You don't have to hard code the value, you can calculate whatever mean you want and pass it in. is the problem you didn't know how to draw the line or didn't know how to calculate the correct mean?

Comment: I can use the abline function, ok! But I first need to calculate the average to place the line on the graph, right?? So, how do I put the calculation of the average according to the orientation I put there in the function I made? Then, it is possible can enter the abline. Sorry if the question was not understandable

Comment: (1) Your dataset contains `2021-08-13` marked as `Sunday`.  (2) How exactly do you calculate the standard derivation?

Comment: Thanks Martin, I adjusted! I inserted an example in excel just for show. The mean calculation is based on the sum of D1 for each day. In the example from excel it is SUM1 and SUM2, in this case it is = (6 + 14) / 2 = 10. Here, I am considering the 1st of August and 8th of August, which are Sundays. If by chance there was one more day on Sunday, the mean would be = (SUM1+SUM2+SUM3)/3, and so on. This mean calculation needs to be in my function before generating the line in the graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you want something like this:

```r
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)


scatter_date <- function(dt, dta = df) {
  
  df <- dta %>%
    mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>%
    group_by(Week, date) %>%
    summarize(across(starts_with("D"), sum), .groups = "drop")
  
  df_mean <- df %>% 
    group_by(Week) %>% 
    mutate(mean = mean(D1)) %>% 
    filter(date == ymd(dt)) %>% 
    pull(mean)
  
  df_sd <- df %>% 
    group_by(Week) %>% 
    mutate(sd = sd(D1)) %>% 
    filter(date == ymd(dt)) %>% 
    pull(sd)
  
  df %>%
    select(-D1) %>% 
    pivot_longer(c(-date, -Week), names_pattern = "DR(.+)", values_to = "val") %>%
    filter(date == ymd(dt)) %>%
    mutate(name = as.numeric(name)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = name, y = val)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    xlab("Days") + 
    ylab("Types") + 
    ylim(0, 20) + 
    xlim(0, 7) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = df_mean, color = "red") +
    geom_hline(yintercept = df_mean + df_sd, 
               color = "blue",
               linetype = 2) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = df_mean - df_sd, 
               color = "blue",
               linetype = 2)
  
}

scatter_date("2021-08-01")
```

[image]

### Scatterplot

I changed the `ylim`.

```r
scatter_date <- function(dt, dta = df) {
  
  df <- dta %>%
    mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>%
    group_by(Week, date) %>%
    summarize(across(starts_with("D"), sum), .groups = "drop")
  
  df_mean <- df %>% 
    group_by(Week) %>% 
    mutate(mean = mean(D1)) %>% 
    filter(date == ymd(dt)) %>% 
    pull(mean)
  
  df_sd <- df %>% 
    group_by(Week) %>% 
    mutate(sd = sd(D1)) %>% 
    filter(date == ymd(dt)) %>% 
    pull(sd)
  
  df %>%
    select(-D1) %>% 
    pivot_longer(c(-date, -Week), names_pattern = "DR(.+)", values_to = "val") %>%
    filter(date == ymd(dt)) %>%
    mutate(name = as.numeric(name)) %>%
    select(-Week, -date) %>% 
    plot(xlab = "Days", 
         ylab = "Types", 
         xlim = c(0, 7), 
         ylim = c((min(.$val) %/% 10) * 10, (max(.$val) %/% 10 + 1) * 10))
    abline(h = df_mean, col = "red")
    abline(h = df_mean - df_sd, col = "blue", lty = 2)
    abline(h = df_mean + df_sd, col = "blue", lty = 2)
}

scatter_date("2021-08-01")
```

returns

[image]

Comment: Very Good Martian! It is exactly that! Would it be possible to leave it as the graph I made? Without using ggplot?

Comment: Last time I checked, I was born on Earth.

Comment: Sorry Martin! This "a" was wrong. The graphic was very good, that was the idea. Just one thing I wanted to understand better in your code: for the day 01/08 and 08/08 ok, but if I choose 13/08 doesn't even appear the scatter plot? It is right?. I will accept your answer anyway!

Comment: Ah, yes, the `ylim` is flawed. I corrected it. Please try again.

Comment: Martin, can you tell me if there are any other forms of scatter plot besides the ones you did in this question (ggplot and scatterplot )?

Comment: What do you have in mind?`ggplot2` provides several methods to change the layout. What are you looking for?

Comment: I was thinking of a more "elegant" scatterplot than these, but I have no idea which one, because I only know these two. Do you know any sites that show you the different ways to do scatter plots by `ggplot` or another package?

Comment: There are some sites, for example https://r-statistics.co/Top50-Ggplot2-Visualizations-MasterList-R-Code.html#Scatterplot%20With%20Encircling but not specialized on scatterplots.